# Azure Mobile SDK vs Custom Code - Scalability

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

We have written two mobile apps and a web back end. Mobile apps are written in Xamarin, back end in C# in Azure.

There is shared data between all three apps, some are simple keyword tables, but some data tables will change, e.g. mobile user is moving around and making some updates to a table, updates need to go back to web app and then possibly out to the apps.

Currently use SQLite on the mobile apps and following a off-line first approach, i.e. user changes a table we write to SQLite on mobile and then sync to server. If user has no connectivity a background process will eventually sync up data to server when possible.

All this is custom code now, and I am a little hesitant to continue on this path. We are in testing with 4 users or so, but expectation is to grow to thousands or tens of thousands of users in 6 to 18 months.

I *think* that our approach might not scale. Would prefer to switch to an Offline first framework instead of continuing to roll our own.

Given our environment I think using Azure Mobile SDK would be the obvious path to follow.

In general would you choose an offline first framework if your app will grow? In particular, any experience with using Azure Mobile SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your question will likely be closed because you're asking for an opinion/recommendation but anyways...

From the Azure Mobile Apps Github repo:

> Please note that the product team is not currently investing in any
>   new feature work for Azure Mobile Apps.

Also to my knowledge, Microsoft has not announced any new SDK or upgrade path.

With that in mind, one option is to keep your custom code and bonify it with code that you'd extract from the SDK or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your mobile app calls a web service, which then performs any necessary writes, you could load test a copy of your production environment to see if things fall over and at what point. I'm not a huge fan of premature optimization.

Assuming things do fall over, you could introduce a shock absorber between your web service endpoint and the database using a Service Bus Queue.